# Should there be a definition for Base dtor?

Tags: c++

Compiler is giving link error and require to provide definition for Base pure virtual destructor.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived(){ std::cout << "Derived dtor"; }
};

int main()
{
       Derived d;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just provide an empty implementation for it (outside the class definition):

```
Base::~Base() { }
```

Being pure-virtual just means that you must override the member function in any concrete derived class; it doesn't mean that it cannot have a body. In the case of the destructor, you *must* supply a body, wether the destructor is pure-virtual or not, since it is invoked by the compiler when you destroy the object.

Just to be clear, you must provide an implementation. Whether it is empty or not is up to you. This is because the compiler generates code that calls the destructor whenever you try to destroy an instance of Base. You could declare a normal virtual Base:

```
virtual ~Base();
```

And never define it. This would be fine as long as you never destroy an instance of Base (questionable conduct, but it would work). However, in your case, Base has a Derived type, which calls the Base class's destructor in its own destructor. That's where your linker error is coming from.

Comment: You mean `virtual ~Base() { }` ;)

Comment: @Mephane: I meant what I wrote. If you read the rest of my answer, it'll make more sense.

Comment: Isn't ~Base already pure virtual?  Why should I provide an empty implementation?

Comment: @Noro: Marcelo gave the reason why you should (actually, why you have to) provide an implementation. The compiler calls the function whether you like it or not, so you have to provide an implementation.

Comment: This syntax doesn't seem to be valid. A pure virtual function must be implemented outside the class (without repeating `= 0`)

Answer (score 3):

Since `Derived` inherits `Base`, destroying a `Derived` object will first call `Derived::~Derived` and then `Base::~Base` (the compiler does this for you - whether you like it or not).

Hence, you have to provide an implementation for `Base::~Base`. Note that this isn't particularly strange. A pure virtual function can have an implementation. 'pure virtual' only means that the class cannot be instantiated.

Comment: In fact, as Marcelo Cantos wrote in his answer, pure virtual means that the function must be overriden in non-abstract child classes.

Comment: @Gorpik: Well that's plain redundant: of course it must be overriden in classes which want to be non-abstract. 'abstract' is defined in terms of whether the class has pure virtual methods or not.

Comment: In a way, you are both right. A pure virtual method means the class cannot be instantiated, which of course means that a derived class must override it in order to *be* instantiated.

Comment: @Gorpik: And a class will have a destructor implicitly, the derived class needn't explicitly override the destructor. - A pure virtual destructor is only useful for not allowing the base to be instantiated (given that the base has no other functions to be made pure), otherwise making the destructor pure is meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There's a non-virtual call of `Base::~Base`, implicitly from `Derived::~Derived`. Therefore the compiler is right to complain that `Base::~Base` must be defined, even if empty.